# xmlrpclib, wsapi4plone - check username and password

Tags: python, plone, xmlrpclib

Here is one of my functions:

```
def connect():
    c = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://username:password@host',
                allow_none=True,
            )
    return c
```

How do I check if the username and password are correct in this method before returning `c`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check if the provided credentials are valid by using this trick (provided that the plone site has wsapi4plone correctly installed):

```
>>> server = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://admin:admin@localhost:8080/plone")
>>> server.get_schema('Document')
{'creators': {'required': False, 'type': 'lines'}, 'description': ...
>>> baduser_server = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://bad:bad@localhost:8080/plone")
>>> baduser_server.get_schema('Document')
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ProtocolError: <ProtocolError for bad:bad@localhost:8080/plone: 401 Unauthorized>
```

So the corresponding code would be:

```
from xmlrpclib import ServerProxy
from xmlrpclib import ProtocolError
try:
    server = ServerProxy("http://admin:admin@localhost:8080/plone")
    server.get_schema('Document')
    return server
except ProtocolError:
    return None
```

Comment: so there's no specific method to check the username and password for plone? hmm I'll try this trick for now